# Android, how to replace initial fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I create this fragment and set initial fragment `FirstFragment`, if I don't set this initial fragment, the app will crash.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.app.FirstFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

And then I use this function to replace the fragment, this works fine, every fragment can be replaced by other fragment except `FirstFragment`, this fragment keep displaying on screen. How can I replace this fragment?

```
enum class FragmentType {
    SETTING, ACTIVITY, PROFILE, CONNECT, SCANNER
}
private fun changeFragmentTo(type: FragmentType) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    when(type) {
        FragmentType.SETTING -> {
            title = "SETTING"
            val f = SettingFragment()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, f)
        }

        FragmentType.ACTIVITY -> {
            title = "ACTIVITY"
            val f = ActivityFragment()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, f)
        }

        FragmentType.PROFILE -> {
            title = "PROFILE"
            val f = ProfileFragment()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, f)
        }
        FragmentType.CONNECT -> {
            title = "CONNECT"
            val f = ConnectFragment()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, f)
        }
        FragmentType.SCANNER -> {
            title = "SCANNER"
            val f = ScannerFragment()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, f)
        }

    }
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of yours is inside the xml. Instead of using `fagment` tag, you should create a layout which will be a container for your fragment.

Change your xml like this:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and reference your `FrameLayout` inside, I assume, activity via it's id `R.id.fragment`:

```
val fragment = SettingFragment()
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
```